# Rollback after successful transaction

Tags: transactions, typeorm

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/transactions.md), the `TypeORM` library explains how to do a basic rollback if a transaction fails.

However, I want to know how I can rollback a *successful* transaction after the query-runner is released.

```
const queryRunner: QueryRunner = dataSource.createQueryRunner();
await queryRunner.connect();

try {
  await queryRunner.startTransaction();
  const entityManager: EntityManager = queryRunner.manager;
  const repository: Repository<Example> = entityManager.getRepository(exampleEntityMap);
  await repository.save(example);
  await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
} catch (error: unknown) {
  await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
  throw error;
} finally {
  await queryRunner.release();
}

// Rollback the transaction that just occurred above.
```

I still have access to the `queryRunner` instance.

Unfortunately, `commitTransaction` doesn't return any kind of transaction ID to rollback this at a later point.

This functionality is critical, so I don't want a work around (i.e. a delete transaction). I feel `rollbackTransaction` should be the answer but the documentation seems to imply that once query-runner is released - I cannot do anything.

Is my only option to remove the `finally` and pass around `queryRunner` to release manually at a later point?